# Http Post multipart file consume apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, http-post, mime

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181670/camel-rest-dsl-retrieve-http-post-multipart-file/54207451#54207451), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415708/apache-camel-multipart-http-post-file-upload) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537409/convert-multipart-body-to-java-object) so please don't flag this as duplicate.

I just want an HTTP-POST multipart form that takes a file & consumes it. What I have already tried as per linked answers.

```
        from("rest:POST:/channel/{payment_mode}/bulk/transfer")
                .id("bulk-transfer")
                .unmarshal().mimeMultipart() //.split().attachments() 
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, SimplePojo.class)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "## Bulk Transfer")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Body:\n%s", exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)));
                    Map<String,Attachment> attachments = exchange.getMessage(AttachmentMessage.class).getAttachmentObjects();
                    DataHandler dataHandler = attachments.get("test.doc").getDataHandler();
                    System.out.println(String.format("Attachments: %s", attachments.size()));
}).to("file:src/main/resources/testUpload");
```

Error I get on running this:

```
05:38:21.781 ERROR [                      XNIO-1 task-1] route10                      : @@ unhandled exception. Body: ÐÏà¡±á>þÿ !#þÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿì¥Áð¿ddddSxSx
Æ&Ð @à°P ðÀ!
i4@ñÿ4NormalCJOJPJQJmH  <A@òÿ¡<Default Paragraph Font
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
GTimes New Roman5Symbol3Arial;Helvetica ðÐhÚKl&ÚKl& ð¥À´´0"ðþÿ
àòùOh«+'³Ù0éýþÿ
ÕÍÕ.+,ù®0éýþÿÿÿ 
þÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿ"þÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿRoot Entryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÀF$1TableÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿWordDocumentÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿSummaryInformation(ÿÿÿÿDocumentSummaryInformation8ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ, stacktrace: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x11
 at [Source: (org.apache.camel.converter.stream.ByteArrayInputStreamCache); line: 1, column: 4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidOther(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3573)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._decodeCharForError(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3318)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3544)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2651)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:856)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:753)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4340)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4189)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3242)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.unmarshal(JacksonDataFormat.java:188)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:702)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:616)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:40)
    at org.apache.camel.component.undertow.UndertowConsumer.handleRequest(UndertowConsumer.java:230)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Why is something as simple as consuming a file so complicated in camel? Please help!

Comment: Did you note (in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181670/camel-rest-dsl-retrieve-http-post-multipart-file that "(...) does not work in case your form contains only *single* input in form"

Comment: Yes. And I did try more than one form input data but still doesn't work.